# For loop in batch file dies calling Windows conversion tool

Tags: parsing, batch-file, for-loop

[ParseRat](https://www.guysoftware.com/pratman.pdf) is an old program that I have had a long time. I need to transpose text files in `c:\wherefilesare`.

I run the below and it just dies:

```
echo on
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd c:\wherefilesare
SET progdir=C:\program files (x86)\ParseRat

for%%x in (*.txt) do ("%%progdir%\parserat.exe" "%%x.txt" "%%progdir%\test.prz" "%%x.csv"
```

Comment: You got an extra percent symbol for all your environmental variables.

Comment: You are also not using the FOR meta-variable correctly.  Essentially `%%x` expands to the actual file name with the extension.  So it will see `file1.txt.txt` and `file1.txt.csv`.  You need to use the command modifiers.  `%%~nx` to get just the file name without the extension.

Comment: Interesting piece of software. Looks similar to an old piece of software I used back in the 90's. The software I used could read and write about 40 different file and DB formats and had it's own functions and scripting language built-in to manipulate the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Squashman says:

> "You (have) an extra percent symbol for all your (environment) variables.  You are also not using the FOR meta-variable correctly. Essentially `%%x` expands to the actual file name with the extension. So it will see `file1.txt.txt` and `file1.txt.csv`. You need to use the command modifiers. `%%~nx` to get just the file name without the extension."

Also, you are missing a closing parenthesis...

```
echo on
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd c:\wherefilesare
SET progdir=C:\program files (x86)\ParseRat

for %%x in (*.txt) do (
    "%progdir%\parserat.exe" "%%~nx.txt" "%progdir%\test.prz" "%%~nx.csv"
)
```

Comment: ok I changed is around a bit to 

echo on
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
CD c:\sarasota
Set pd=C:\program files (x86)\ParseRat\


For %%x IN (*.txt) DO ("%%pd%parserat.exe" "%%x.txt" "%%pd%test.prz" "%%~nx.csv")

Pause
Cls

and my output is

c:\sarasota>("%pdC:\program files (x86)\ParseRat\test.prz" "bradenton-mortgage.csv" ) 

c:\sarasota>("%pdC:\program files (x86)\ParseRat\test.prz" "bradenton-nursinghome.csv" ) 

c:\sarasota>("%pdC:\program files (x86)\ParseRat\test.prz" "bradenton-nutrition.csv" )

Comment: weird it is not picking up on the variable to set the program path

Comment: @jack, comments are not meant for that much code.  As you can see it is extremely difficult to read.  If you have updated code you need help with you edit your question above. Please delete your comment with the code.

Comment: @jack If your question is answered, use the check mark to "accept" it.  It's a "just-the-facts" sort of place, so no need to put introductions or signatures on questions...or thanks in comments...accepting the answer is the thanks.  :-)